# Socket get incomplete data from server

Tags: java, sockets

I have java application deployed in weblogic the principal role from app is the communication with another API via socket. This another API is installed in another server. Ok

Sometime to here the java app started getting incomplete data from socket. I have analyzed the logs on the API side. The API return complete data but on weblogic server where java app is deployed not read complete data. Locally the java app work as well.

I suppose that it have something with server memory. I have no idea to solve this problem.

I search on google but have no answers.

Below this original message returned locally with succes:

> @**@0 100-Autorizado o uso da NF-e    33170845242914003465652000000007511200000067    http://www4.fazenda.rj.gov.br/retrieve/QRCode?chNFe=33170845242914003465652000000007511200000067&nVersao=100&tpAmb=2&cDest=12345678998&dhEmi=323031372d30382d31385431333a30343a32302d30333a3030&vNF=110.00&vICMS=22.80&digVal=6b6e3774696b652f616b4878574a35414d766367347074497a62343d&cIdToken=000001&cHashQRCode=998144c803f3f5e56a0e1764647ccd6928c2a70d 333170000817607|2017-08-18T13:04:23-03:00|SVRSnfce201707171030|100  http://www4.fazenda.rj.gov.br/consultaNFCe/QRCode?  6989*@@*

Below is message returned in weblogic server incomplete:

> @**@0 100-Autorizado o uso da NF-e    33170845242914003465652000000007501000000449    http://www4.fazenda.rj.gov.br/consultaNFCe/QRCode?chNFe=33170845242914003465652000000007501000000449&nVersao=100&tpAmb=2&cDest=22233344405&dhEmi=323031372d30382d31385431323a35343a30342d30333a3030&vNF=325.00&vICMS=61.75&digVal=7955796b6b4e64687a7342335470755166495847516c4343566e453d&cIdToken=000001&cHashQRCode=03e10ca5299ed5cb5acd7de5dc5db98df9c49d0e 333170000817573|2017-08-18T12:54:06-03:00|SVRSnfce201707171030|100  http://www4.fazenda.rj.go

Below is responsible class to send and read data:

```
@Repository
```

public class SocketRepository implements BaseRepository {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketRepository.class);

private Socket socket;
private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

private BufferedOutputStream bos;
private BufferedInputStream bis;

@Override
public synchronized String sendDataSocket(String buff, final OsbRequestDTO osbDto) throws Exception {

    try {

        LOGGER.info("start send data. ");

        URL url = new URL(osbDto.getEmissor().getUrlLoja());
        openConnection(url.getHost(), url.getPort());

        if (this.bos == null) {
            this.bos = new BufferedOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        if (this.bis == null) {
            this.bis = new BufferedInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        this.bos.write(buff.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        this.bos.flush();

        LOGGER.info("end send data. ");
        return readMessagePaperless(bis);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erro :" + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    } finally {
        LOGGER.info("start finally block. ");
        closeConnection();
        LOGGER.info("End finally block.");
    }
}

private String readMessagePaperless(final BufferedInputStream bis) throws IOException {

    try {
        LOGGER.info("start read data .");
        byte[] bufferSize = new byte[512 * 1024];
        int data = bis.read(bufferSize);
        if (data == -1) {
            return "";
        }
        LOGGER.info("end read data.");
        return new String(bufferSize, 0, data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("err." + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}

private void closeConnection() throws Exception {
    try {

        if (this.bos != null && this.bis != null) {
            try {
                this.bos.close();
                this.bis.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("err  :" + e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }

        }

        if (this.socket == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.socket.close();
        this.socket = null;
        this.bis = null;
        this.bos = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("err :" + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}

private void openConnection(final String host, final int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    LOGGER.info("start open socket conn.");

    if (this.socket != null) {
        return;
    }
    this.socket = new Socket(host, port);
    LOGGER.info("end.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The read will only read a chunk of data as provided by the network, normally around 1500 bytes depending on various factors. You should continue reading until you have received the complete message. When the connection is local it works differently.

Comment: So I do it. I have method readMessage that stop when data == -1 end of string returned.

Comment: Then there must be more code which you did not include that loops over readMessagePaperless and something is wrong there.

Comment: @danillonc: Even with such a method, `readMessagePaperless()` is wrong, for the reasons stated.

Comment: I increment more code to method readMessagePaperless and now getting complete data.
`while((data = bis.read(bufferSize)) != -1){
    msg.append(new String(bufferSize, 0, data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   }`